Flutter Barcode Scanner Problem in Release Mode
I'm developing an app which uses the 'flutter_barcode_scanner' package, latest version. in debug mode everything is working fine. However when I try to build the app in release mode scanner screen doesn't show and I get this message in the terminal:
'E/FlutterBarcodeScannerPlugin( 6160): startView: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.abaad_stock/com.amolg.flutterbarcodescanner.BarcodeCaptureActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?'
And sometimes this message appears (not during every build):
'e: /Users/mohamedradwan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.'
Here is what I've tried so far:

added this code to both profile and debug 'AndroidManifest.xml' files:

<activity android:name="com.example.abaad_stock/com.amolg.flutterbarcodescanner.BarcodeCaptureActivity"></activity>

deleted the 'android/.gradle' folder

It's worth noting that I have used the same package a couple of months ago and it worked just fine. Any ideas?

if its in release mode then only AndroidManifest file which resides in android/main/ folder will work you have added for debug and profile instead of only add in main manifest file

If you check the Repo of the package you see what has been configured for Android in the Manifest.xml file:
https://github.com/AmolGangadhare/flutter_barcode_scanner/blob/master/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
Check if the permission for camera is also needed.

@HardikMehta I believe that only one Activity tag is allowed in the main folder right?

@AndroDevs No camera permission is required, I wrote the permission code though, still doesn't work
